# PyAutoGui always returns none for locateOnScreen

Tags: python, pyautogui

My pyautogui always returns none for images. The images are in the same folder as the program. The image names are the same I have them saved as. The images are up to date and definitely on my screen. Please help, pyautogui always returns none for locateOnScreen. Here is my code:

```
import time
import sys
import pyautogui

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.size()

width, height = pyautogui.size()


y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('LOLicon.png')
print(y)
for i in range(2):
    x = pyautogui.moveTo(y)
    pyautogui.click(x)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.doubleClick()

del x
del y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
import sys
import pyautogui

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.size()

width, height = pyautogui.size()

y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('LOLicon.png')
print(y)
for i in range(2):
    x = pyautogui.moveTo(y[0:2])
    pyautogui.click(x)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.doubleClick()
```

This above works perfectly. The only change in code is `x = pyautogui.moveTo(y[0:2])`.

So make sure that **the image is actually on screen while you are running your script** (not hidden by the code editor or other window) and **the image content of `LOLicon.png` is actually what you assume it is**.

It could be also helpful to check out if this code:

```
import pyautogui
im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(20, 20, 50, 50)) 
im.save("myScreenshot.png")
y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("myScreenshot.png")
print(y)
x = pyautogui.moveTo(y[0:2])
```

runs fine without an error. If it does, you can rename `myScreenshot.png` to `LOLicon.png` and adjust `region=(20, 20, 50, 50)` so, that it captures the LOLicon on the screen.

Check out https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html?highlight=save%20image for details of the screenshot functions in pyautogui and make sure the required modules are installed ( Pillow and eventually scrot if you are on Linux ).

Comment: It still displays this when I try to run it:           None
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python\Projects\LOLsignin.py", line 15, in <module>
        x = pyautogui.moveTo(y[0:2])
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please check out the updated answer and try out the provided further code.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you!